# Programa Java en Netbeans con swing

Tags: java, java-swing

Me podéis porque pueden salir estos errores o algún sitio donde dar el programa para que me encuentren el fallo.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at transformador.Transformador.Transformar(Transformador.java:45)
    at Interfaz.Ventana.transformarFs(Ventana.java:173)
    at Interfaz.PanelGenerarFicheros.btnaceptarActionPerformed(PanelGenerarFicheros.java:107)
    at Interfaz.PanelGenerarFicheros.access$100(PanelGenerarFicheros.java:12)
    at Interfaz.PanelGenerarFicheros$2.actionPerformed(PanelGenerarFicheros.java:43)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82
```

)

Comment: Empieza por corregir el primer error porque suelen ir en cascada: Transformador.java:45 quieres decir que se esta produciendo en la línea 45 de Trasformador.java, tendrías que aportar el código suficiente y necesario para reproducir tu error para obtener más ayuda.

Comment: Si sólo compartes el error que recibes sin compartir el código que lo causa, no podemos darte más que consejos generales sobre cómo solucionar el problema. Debes añadir un [mcve] a la pregunta. Además, deberías hacer algo de investigación y búsqueda en el sitio, se han realizado bastantes preguntas iguales a esta, el código puede ser diferente, pero la causa de raíz es la misma. Busca "NullPointerException" en el sitio y encontrarás respuestas.